# Stop W10 IME from changing when focused on non-unicode program

Tags: windows-10, language, ime

1. I'm on Windows 10 22H2 build 19045.3930
2. I typically use the `Chinese language` IME but in `English mode`, it basically lets me type in English as per normal and pressing `win+space` toggles between typing in Chinese and English
3. However, when I focus on certain apps, Windows automatically switches the IME to `English language` and sticks to it even when I focus back to other windows, e.g. Outlook 2003 is 1 such app (Why I'm using it is really besides the point)
4. While in `English language` IME, pressing `win+space` has no effect, so I need to use my mouse and switch my IME back to `Chinese language` to get back my desired behavior
5. What can I do to make my IME always stay in `Chinese language`?
6. I did try to change my `Language for non-Unicode programs` to `Chinese language` under the `Administrative` tab of `Region`, but that makes several windows including the console and Task Manager use an ugly font, so no go.